# Running python script in PHP script

Tags: python, php

I'm trying to run a python script inside php script, my python file creates a plot and I want that plot to get displayed within the php page.
But when I run the code it doesn't display anything.. does any one have any idea why ? how to fix this please ?
Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
```

Php script

```
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('python test.py');
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED ANSWER:

I have replicated your issue and resolved through a few changes to the PHP and Python files.

Try these amendments:

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.savefig(sys.stdout)
```

The addition of the environment comment at the top ensures that python runs in the correct environment when called from PHP.

The bottom line ensures that python outputs the generated image to the stdout so that PHP can receive it.

PHP file:

```
<?php

  // use output buffering to prevent passthru outputting the returned image code immediately.
  ob_start();
  passthru('python test.py');
  // Store the binary image data (png format) to $raw variable
  $raw = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
    
?>
<!-- output the image by base64_encoding it -->
<!-- could also look at using GD to store the image to a file on the webserver for direct access in HTML -->
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <?=base64_encode($raw)?>" alt="image" />
```

These two files should result in PHP running the python command, storing the returned binary image to the `$raw` variable and using output buffering to prevent `passthru` automatically dumping the output to the browser.
`Passthru` is used here in preference to either `exec` or `shell_exec` as it handles a binary output from the command being run correctly (`exec` splits the returned image binary into various array elements that aren't always easily reassembled.

---

Original answer below for explanation of comments.

When using `shell_exec` you have to chain your command with an echo statement to get the results. E.g. something like:

```
shell_exec("python test.py 2>&1; echo $?");
```

Look at using `exec($command, $output)` instead - taking note of the parameters for `exec` to ensure that an output value is returned. Also the optional 3rd parameter that would let you check for any result codes. (see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php for the manual)

As always with running relatively high level commands like these - be extremely careful.

Comment: Still no output at all? Have you checked that the user that php/your webserver is running under has correct permissions to execute the python script?

Comment: Yes, because when I try this function with just text print it does work fine.

Comment: How have you tested the python script? Does it output when you run this on the command line (as PHP would)?

I'd expect some more lines in your test.py to output the chart?

Comment: yes... everything looks normal I did alot of googling but couldn't figure out what's wrong

Comment: So you can run python test.py on the command line and see the graph?

Comment: Can you please maybe give it a try ? @steve

Comment: Sure - will give it a go shortly and report back.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working solution for you. Please add any further comments here if you need any more explanation.

Comment: ```<img src="data:image/png;base64, <?=base64_encode($raw)?>" alt="image" />```I don't get this part my image will be saved in ftp, so don't know how to adapted or if it will work

Comment: So by default your python script returns the raw binary of a png image file. For demo purposes in the above I've output this in the HTML. When you say saved to FTP do you mean just saved to your server? If so you'd instead use the $raw variable and the GD function imagecreatefromstring to save the data returned from Python to a .png file.